# Facebook API: get the posts that are shares of a given post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to find the posts that are shares of a give post on facebook. I am using the graph api and the docs say it's possible by making use of the sharedposts object:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/object/sharedposts

**BUT** using it returns an empty data set, although there are shares of the given posts.

Is there a way to get those shared posts?

Comment: To be able to read any post made by a user profile, that user would need to login to your app and grant it `user_posts` permission first. So all shares made by users for which that is not the case, are not visible to your app.

Comment: What if the shared post is by a public page? Can the shared post  be seen then? Usually, for public pages there is no need for `user_posts` permission to see the posts of the page.

Comment: Yes, if a page shared it publicly, you should get those.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @CBroe can we get information about "who have shared our post"using sharedposts object?  or it just returning numbers of count?

Comment: @Radhey /sharedposts returns a list of post objects, but only those that are visible to your app. For shares made by users that would mean, the user would have to be a user of your app & have granted it permission to read their posts.

Comment: bit confused!
let say (consider privacy is open), I have post one image -> you will share it in your network
now its level one.
now if some of your friend list share that post from your time line then I 'm able to see that who as fb user have shared my post ?